# Stored Procedure w/ Multiple Queries in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

Let me start by saying my knowledge of stored procedures is very basic.  I know how to write basic queries and return values in VBA.  I also know that you can basically write programs from within SQL which is where my knowledge breaks down.  I just don't have to do it enough.  Anyway, in VBA, I run a series of queries.  As I feared in the conception phase of this project, it creates some real performance issues to run too many queries from a single routine.  Here is the routine.

```
Public Sub linePoll()

    errorPosition = "aofResults.linePoll"
    On Error GoTo errorTrap
    Err.Clear

    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstA As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstB As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstC As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstD As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstE As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim packQty As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim formFactor As Integer

    m = 0
    constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=i.p.add.ress;initial catalog=catalog;user id=user;password=password"
    Set conn = New ADODB.connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    conn.Open constr
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "Getting order quantity"
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ISNULL(SUM(lQ.[QUANTITY]), 0) FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER]"
    Set rst = cmd.execute                        'Get total order quantity, may change if inventory depletes.
    If Not rst.EOF = True Then
        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Found order quantity as " & rst(0)
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\soQuantity")
        eTag.value = rst(0)
    Else
                LogDiagnosticsMessage "No order found in line queue DB"
    End If
    If Not rst(0) = 0 Then
        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Getting optic order quantity packed"
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER) FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [SO_LINE_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = oQ.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER) AND [REJECT] = 'False'"
        Set rst = cmd.execute
        If Not rst.EOF = True Then
            LogDiagnosticsMessage "Found optics order quantity packed as " & rst(0)
            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\soQuantityPacked")
            eTag.value = rst(0)
        Else
                    LogDiagnosticsMessage "No packed optics found in results DB"
        End If
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("Machine\itoSettings0") 'Evaluate packing quantity against machine settings (stored in DB, written to PLC at first startup)
        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Evaluating manual pack need"
        If rst(0) < eTag.value Then
            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\manualPack") 'Evaluate packing quantity
            eTag.value = True
        Else
            eTag.value = False
        End If
        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Getting the top line order information"
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER],lQ.[QUANTITY],lQ.[SELECTED],lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID], lQ.[FINISHED_PART_NUMBER], ISNULL(lQ.[OEM_PART_NUMBER], ''),ISNULL(lQ.[COMPATIBILITY], ''), oQ.[INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING], oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] WHERE lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lQ.[SELECTED] DESC,lQ.[COMPLETED] ASC"
        Set rstA = cmd.execute()                     'Returns the line orders associated to the sales order
        If Not rstA.EOF = True Then
            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\SOLineNumber")
            If Not eTag.value = rstA(0) Then        '************************************Updates the line order if the line order is different than what's already selected
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\SOLineNumber")
                eTag.value = rstA(0)
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\QuantityOrdered")
                eTag.value = rstA(1)
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\FinishedPartNumber")
                eTag.value = rstA(4)
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\OEMPartNumber")
                eTag.value = rstA(5)
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\Compatibility")
                eTag.value = rstA(6)
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\IndividualPack") 'PLC expects "Double Pack" true\false, ITO sends "Single Pack" true\false
                eTag.value = Not rstA(7)
            End If                                  '************************************
            LogDiagnosticsMessage "Getting the quantity of parts passed for this line order"
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]) FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [SERIAL_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] rL WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]) AND oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0)
            Set rstB = cmd.execute()                 'Returns the count of the parts associated to the above line order that passed
            If Not rstB.EOF = True Then
                Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\QuantityPassed")
                eTag.value = rstB(0)
                LogDiagnosticsMessage "Evaluating parts remaining for this line order as " & rstB(0)
                Select Case rstB(0)        'Evaluate Qty left to process in active line order
                    Case Is = 0                          'Qty Zero (Line order complete)
                            LogDiagnosticsMessage "Setting line order as completed"
                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'False', [COMPLETED] = 'True' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0)
                            cmd.execute                      'Unselect the currently index line order and Set order as completed
                            LogDiagnosticsMessage "Checking line order quantity against sales order quantity"
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]) FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER]) - (SELECT COUNT(lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]) FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] WHERE lQ.[COMPLETED] = 'True'))"
                            Set rstD = cmd.execute()         'Check line queue quantity associated to the sales order, count the line orders associated to the current sales order in the queue that are incomplete
                            'Set the currently indexed line order as selected
                            If rstD(0) = 0 Then
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] WHERE [SELECTED] = 'True'"
                            Set rstE = cmd.execute()
                                If Not rstE.EOF = False Then
                                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\soFinished")
                                    eTag.value = True
                                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\PLC_FinishBox")
                                    If eTag.value = 1 Then
                                        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Checking whether or not the PLC ready to complete the order"
                                        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\PLC_CompleteOrder") 'Checks that order fulfillment mode is turned off
                                        If eTag.value = 1 Then
                                            boxNum = 0
                                            LogDiagnosticsMessage "Unselecting sales order " & rstA(8) & ", deleting results for this sales order, and setting status to ERP"
                                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'False' WHERE [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = '" & rstA(8) & "'"
                                            cmd.execute          'Set's the current sales order selected bit to off
                                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[MACHINE_STATE] SET [STATUS] = 'USER' where [OPERATING_STATE] = 2"
                                            cmd.execute          'sets the status back to USER
                                            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS]"
                                            cmd.execute
                                            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\orderFulfillmentMode")
                                            eTag.value = 0
                                            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\PLC_CompleteOrder")
                                            eTag.value = 0
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                                rstE.Close
                            Else
                                rstA.MoveNext                'Index to the next line order in the record set
                                LogDiagnosticsMessage "Indexing to the next order in the list, setting" & rstA(0) & " selected."
                                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'True' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0)
                                cmd.execute
                                rstD.Close
                            End If
                    Case Is > 0                          'Qty Remaining > Line Order Qty (Line Order Select)
                        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Getting the form factor for this line order"
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT fF.[FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[FORM_FACTOR] AS fF LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ ON lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] = fF.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] WHERE lQ.[SELECTED] = 'True'"
                        Set rstC = cmd.execute()         'Returns the form factor description that is currently selected in the order line queue
                        If Not rstC.EOF = True Then
                            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\FormFactor")
                            eTag.value = rstC(0)
                            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\NextOpticXFP")
                            Select Case rstC(0)
                            Case Is = "XFP"
                                eTag.value = True
                            Case Is <> "XFP"
                                eTag.value = Not True
                            End Select
                        End If
                        rstC.Close
                        LogDiagnosticsMessage "Setting " & rstA(0) & " as selected"
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'True' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0)
                        cmd.execute                      'Set line as selected
                    Case Else
                    End Select
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Error: No line orders exist for sales order " & rstA(4) & ".")
                End If
        ElseIf rstA.EOF = True Then
            MsgBox ("Error: No sales order exists or no line orders associated to sales order: " & rstA(4) & " exists.")
        End If
    End If
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item("AOF\ITO_OpticsReady")
    eTag.value = True

    GoTo cleanExit

cleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rst Is Nothing Then
        rst.Close
    End If
    If Not rstA Is Nothing Then
        rstA.Close
    End If
    If Not rstB Is Nothing Then
        rstB.Close
    End If
    If Not rstC Is Nothing Then
        rstC.Close
    End If
    If Not rstD Is Nothing Then
        rstD.Close
    End If
    If Not rstE Is Nothing Then
        rstE.Close
    End If
    conn.Close
    Exit Sub

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "_Eventwatcher2.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume cleanExit

End Sub
```

So, my thought here is to put more processing on the server side.  I have created individual stored procedures to encapsulate most of these queries, but it didn't have a strong enough effect on the performance.  My main thought that brings me here now is, can I put all this into a single stored procedure?  If I execute seven queries from a stored procedure, how do I handle that in the VBA code?  How is one query differentiated from the next?  How do I use output from a query as input on another query from within a stored procedure?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: So I am consolidating the queries that I use select statements.  I ended up with the following, which seems to work.

```
Private Sub Button1_Released() 

    Dim rst(1 To 8) As ADODB.Recordset

    errorPosition = "ThisDisplay.Button1 Test"
    On Error GoTo errorTrap
    Err.Clear


    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=i.p.add.ress;initial catalog=CATALOG;user id=user;password=pass"
    conn.Open constr

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "rt_test"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 2
    End With

    Set rst(1) = cmd.Execute()
    For i = 2 To 8
        Set rst(i) = rst(i - 1).NextRecordset
    Next
    i = 1
    GoTo cleanExit

cleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 8
        If Not rst(i) Is Nothing Then
            rst(i).Close
        End If
    Next
    conn.Close

    Exit Sub

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "_Eventwatcher2.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.Number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume cleanExit

End Sub
```

Final Update:

A small change to the above yielded the results I needed.  As it turns out, ADO closes the previous recordset automatically when the NextRecordSet method is called.  So instead I needed to open the recordset, then clone it into the array, then move to the next recordset.
I added another recordset that acts as a placeholder.

```
Dim recordSet, rst(1 To 8) As ADODB.recordSet
```

Then modified my code as follows:

```
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Needed to index through and clone recordsets
conn.Open constr

With cmd 'Run stored procedure
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = "rt_test"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 2
End With

Set recordSet = cmd.execute()

For i = 1 To 8
    Set rst(i) = recordSet.Clone
    Set recordSet = recordSet.NextRecordset
Next
...
...
...
cleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next

    If Not recordSet Is Nothing Then
        recordSet.Close
    End If

    For i = 1 To 8
        If Not rst(i) Is Nothing Then
            rst(i).Close
        End If
    Next
    conn.Close

    Exit Sub

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "_Eventwatcher2.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume cleanExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably a better approach could be to try get the final result set needed, and only if it fails then try to detect the reason by more queries.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit more complex than you think, I'm afraid.

The performance issue might be due to the queries themselves, not the way they are executed. If you run all the procedures from SSMS, what is the performance? OK, similar to running them from Excel? Perhaps you need to do some tuning - not necessarily easy task, but there are tools to do it automatically. At the display estimated execution plan for individual queries and see if the tool will recommend an index which might help a lot.

You can run a SP returning multiple record sets. Generally you will get one object - RecordSet - normally with the results of the first query. You work with it normally, once you finish you call method NextRecordset and you will get access to the RecordSet of the second query and so on.

Unfortunately the T-SQL part looks like a lot more work than just answering your question.

Comment: Something I am considering is combining all my queries into one SP, and executing it once rather than creating multiple queries.  I feel my performance issues may be network speed.  If I only have to query once, the problem may disappear.  Something I realized after I wrote this is these problems could be due to the fact that I am testing from a Virtual Machine connected to the customers network via VPN.  I'd be willing to bet I will see a marked increase in performance if I am local to the server.  What tools are you referring to?

Comment: If I write an SP with multiple queries, how do I use the results from one query across other queries within the SP?

Comment: Few options. Easiest to execute would be to result it into temporary table so  if you have a query like SELECT ... FROM .... .... change it into SELECT ... INTO #someName FROM ... .... and then use #someName just like a table wherever you need in the procedure. The temporary would be dropped after sp finishes (practically speaking). So you can i.e. join it with other tables etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there an easy way to port my code such that I can set rstA as the second record set, rstB as the third record set, etc?

Comment: I'll probably change the letters to numbers and index through a loop.

Comment: I ended up with this and it seems to work.  Will keep posted about performance improvements.